# detect underline and strike through

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to detect with JavaScript/jQuery if an element is strike-through *and* underlined.

So let's say we have:

```
<u><s>text here.</s>other text here.</u>
```

Is it possible to detect if the text within `<s>` is also underlined?

*Ideally, it would not be allowed to look if `<u>` has any `<s>` children.

I've been toying around with it and it seems peculiar that both styles use the same CSS property, which  in turn makes me wonder how it even works in the first place.

To make my problem clearer:

I'm playing around with a self-made wysiwyg editor, for usability reasons I'm trying to implement a listener on the text which alters (lights up) editing buttons. e.g. when a part of text is bold the "B" button changes to an active state. I'm currently handling this by getting the element at the cursor and checking if the element is bold or inherits it.

The problem with underline and striketrough is that they are neither overwriting the text-decoration attribute of each other, and are not visible in css

when I put the cursor on a underlined text-fragment, the `text-decoration` property only shows as `underline`, while the text is both `underline` and `line-through`. In such situations I cannot know what the exact relation is between the `<u>` element and the `<s>` element; the `<s>` element could be 100 parents back as far as I could know.

A lot of text, but I hope it kinda clears up my situation.

Comment: You can insert it in any invisible element and check for `$('u s').length` in it

Comment: what if the combination is `<s><u></u></s>` or even something like `<s><div><u></u></div><p><u></u></p></s>` (just to cover my bases).

Comment: @Rebirth Check my answer. It works even if style is provided through CSS.

Comment: @Rebirth can you just walk all over the parents and check their `text-decoration`s?

Comment: I probably could but I'm not sure that's a smart move with `R` posibilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the robust way of doing it. @Cheery answer works well but it fails if italic or underline or any other font-style provided through CSS. Credit is given to Tim Down for his numerous answers for these kind of questions.

```
 function checkState(element, check) {
    var doc = document;
    var text = doc.getElementById(element);

    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }

    var range, checked = false;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel && sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            document.designMode = "on";
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
    if (document.queryCommandState) {
        checked = document.queryCommandState(check);
    }
    if (document.designMode == "on") {
        document.designMode = "off";
    }
    if (window.getSelection) {
        if (window.getSelection().empty) { // Chrome
            window.getSelection().empty();
        } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) { // Firefox
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    } else if (document.selection) { // IE?
        document.selection.empty();
    }
    return checked;
}

alert(checkState('c', 'underline')); // italic, bold etc..
```

Comment: I've seen alot from Tim Down, and what he does is beyond awesome, currently looking if this suits me.

Comment: It checks out, due to the use of execCommand the browser seems to save the commands and indeed remembers if an element is striked through and/or underlined. thank you red (and indirectly Tim Down)

Comment: It works perfect but hides carret in contenteditable div. How to make carret not disappear?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = '<u><s>text here.</s>other text here.</u>';
var el = $('<div>').html(str);
alert($('u s', el).length);
```

> what if the combination is  or even something like

so what, check inverse too..

```
var str = '<s><div><u></u></div><p><u></u></p></s>';
var el = $('<div>').html(str);
alert($('u s', el).length || $('s u', el).length);
```

if the initial string is not a valid html then you do not know how some browsers will behave at its output.

ps: made some simple example, by click..

```js
$(function(){
  $('.wrapper').on('click', '*', function() {
  var styles = ['line-through', 'underline'], counter = [0, 0], tags = ['S', 'U'];
  $(this).parentsUntil('.wrapper').andSelf().each(function() {
    var current = $(this).css('text-decoration'), $tag = $(this)[0];
    $.each(styles, function(index, style) {
        if (current.indexOf(style) > -1 || $tag.tagName == tags[index]) counter[index] += 1;
    });
  });
  var results = [];
  if (counter[0] > 0) results.push('striked');
  if (counter[1] > 0) results.push('underlined');
  alert(results.join(' and '));
  return false;
});
});
```

```css
.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='strike'>
    striked <u>underlined</u>
</div>

<div class='underline'>
    underlined <s>striked</s>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rebirth then explain in more details, with examples.

Comment: @Cheery Your answer will not work if style is provided through CSS, check my answer.

Comment: @redV He gave the string only, he never said how and where he is going to use it.

Comment: @Cheery From the first line of his question `Is there any way to detect with javascript/jquery if an element is striked through AND underlined.` I assumed that he want to check on HTML element.

Comment: @redV read carefully. He is making wysiwyg. It does not mean that the html code will use the css style of the current page or will be used on the current page. There are much more problems with that.

Comment: @Cheery I agree with you point on he may not use it in current page, but yes, It depends on how he is handling styling. If he does not add any styling but wrap the text with tags, your solution looks absolutely fine.

Comment: @redV I'm not adding styling around <u> and <s> tags (or B/I tags for that matter), I'm just not sure how I can implement this while my startpoint is the child.

Comment: @Rebirth give me some time, I'll try to write something.

Comment: @Rebirth actually the answer of David has the most part of what is needed here.

Comment: Will do, thank you for the effort. The fact that I'm already widely using ranges and execcommand meant that I could handle it with 1 line of code: `document.queryCommandState(state)`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat horrible approach, but the only way I could see that doesn't involve explicitly checking nesting, or relying on default CSS surviving any theming (`<s>` won't always, necessarily, have `text-decoration: line-through;`, similarly `<u>` won't always, necessarily, have `text-decoration: underline;`):

```
// the text-decoration styles you want to find:
var styles = ['line-through', 'underline'];

// finding all elements within the <body>, and
// filtering them:
var underlinedAndLineThrough = $('body *').filter(function() {
    // caching because of re-use:
    var self = $(this),
        decor = self.css('text-decoration');

    // if the 'text-decoration' style is found in the array of styles we're
    // looking for:
    if (styles.indexOf(decor) > -1) {
        // we add that style as a class-name to the current element, and all
        // descendants:
        self.find('*').add(self).addClass(decor);
        // we return the current element (to keep it in the collection):
        return self;
    }
// filtering again:
}).filter(function(){
    // we keep the current element of the collection if it has all the css styles
    // we're looking for:
    return $(this).is('.' + styles.join('.'));
});

console.log(underlinedAndLineThrough);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/07920scq/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- jQuery:

  - [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).